# Seattle City Buildings Data Set

Tags: usa, data.gov

I am working on project where I need Seattle City Buildings Data Set.

- I found Building permits data set, this data set contains only buildings in the last 5 years.
  https://data.seattle.gov/Permitting/Building-Permits-Current/mags-97de

Finding more relevant informations about building age, how many person live in this building would very helpful. 
Any ideas where I can find these data sets. I can gather different data sets or crawl websites if needed.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the building permit database, Seattle.gov provides a dataset for historic buildings at:
https://data.seattle.gov/browse?tags=historic+register

Any building in Seattle that is a public housing or multi-family housing inspected for public housing assistance program will have info in this HUD dataset:
http://www.huduser.org/portal/datasets/pis.html

The footprints and building heights are commercially available ($1571) at:
http://market.weogeo.com/datasets/nokia-here-buildings-seattle-wa-metro-region.html

Other than that, the best way to get this information free (or near FREE) is to go to the property tax office for King County and see if they provide a electronic copy (e.g., like on a CD) for a fee.

UPDATE: I found some more links on building lot outline in major cities open data. This comes from stackexchange question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2046/where-can-i-find-building-footprint-data/2050#2050

Chicago: http://data.cityofchicago.org/Government/Boundaries-Buildings/w2v3-isjw

Seattle: http://data.seattle.gov/dataset/2009-Building-Outlines/y7u8-vad7

Bellingham: http://www.cob.org/services/maps/gis/index.aspx

Bloomington: http://bloomington.in.gov/documents/viewDocument.php?document_id=1870

Spokane: http://www.spokanecity.org/services/gis/data/

Kitsap County: http://www.kitsapgov.com/gis/metadata/

There is also some [additional data for several cities](https://www.data.gov/cities/community/cities/datasets) across the U.S. and federal data on building permits from Data.gov.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes, Taxe office idea is very good one, but unfortunately I am not in seattle right now! I am doing a case study about different cities included Seattle.

Comment: Thank you for your update. Building outlines dataset doesn't help a lot, as it doesn't have releavant information about neither owner nor building like the one from Nokia. Maybe I should reverse-engineering the prob by start thinking about building's owners to find data about buildings